# the buttons align bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like some help about a little problem with my HTML and BOOTSTRAP.

I would like to align two radio buttons side by side but It doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4 pr20">
        <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Mode d'affichage : <h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
        <span>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="envois" id="oui" value="oui" checked />
                <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Factures à régler <h2>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="envois" id="non" value="non"/>
                <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Toutes mes factures <h2>
            </label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What did you suggest me?

If you have got a piece of advice...

Ale.

Oh yeah I corrected somme mistakes :

```
<!------">Mode d'affichage ..." text------------------------------------------------------->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 pr20">
                                <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Mode d'affichage : </h2>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 " style="display:inline-block;">

                                <span>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">

                                        <input type="radio" name="envois" id="oui" value="oui" checked />
                                        <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Factures à régler <h2>
                                    </label>

                                    <label class="radio-inline" style="display:inline-block;">

                                        <input type="radio" name="envois" id="non" value="non"/>
                                        <h2 class="proxima-nova s18">Toutes mes factures <h2>

                                    </label>
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

But I haven't got the result wanted already.

I'd like to do a thing like that : ° FACTURES    ° TOUTES...

If you have got any suggestions...

Ale.

Comment: You have two h2 tags. do you want them to still be over each radio button? or is the 2nd one should be under the two radio buttons?

Comment: Just to make myself clear are you looking for something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/f7avs/

Comment: @Quantico That's how bootstrap has it anyway.

Comment: Your h2 tags aren't closed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if bootstrap has a radio-inline, but if it did, both elements would have the class `radio-inline`, not just the one.

Otherwise, give it a class and then in that class have `display:inline-block;` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork this over to you its on code pen http://codepen.io/CarraraWebsiteSolutions/pen/glxiy not to sure if thats what you are meaning it uses bootstratp 3 mark up the bootstrap 3 style sheet is linked in the html tag icon